# angularJS hide/show initially

Tags: angularjs

Modified example works fine AFTER I've changed the input value
- initially hide/show does the exact opposite of what I want ? ( Hello "" )
Do I need to run some sort of on-ready-go() ?

```
<!doctype html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter your name">
        <hr>
        <h1 ng-show="yourName == ''">Who ARE you ?</h1>
        <h1 ng-hide="yourName == ''">Hello "{{yourName}}"</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you initialize `yourName` to something in the controller? Or is it = `undefined`?

Comment: And I cannot see any `ng-app` / `ng-controller` in your html

Comment: Just started on angularJS today - the code above is ALL there is..

Comment: I advice you to follow this tutorial : https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js It will explain this from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `ng-init` here

```
<input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter your name" ng-init="yourName = ''">
```

here is the [Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/de87EpxmoxA8lXBoVfh0?p=preview)

**OR** use

```
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter your name">
    <hr>
    <h1 ng-show="!yourName">Who ARE you ?</h1>
    <h1 ng-hide="!yourName">Hello "{{yourName}}"</h1>
</div>
```

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wgXPutLgoY8Tn6t7H9w6?p=preview)

**problem**

`yourName` scope variable is `undefined` until your first change on that value. if you change the value once then there is a scope variable called `yourName`. you can see if you type and then backspace the textbox `Who ARE you ?` will print because at this point there is a variable called `yourName`.

you can initialize the variable using `ng-init` and then there is a variable called `yourName` in the scope. so `yourName` is not `undefined`.

as a second example `!yourName`,  if `yourName` `undefined` or `''` then `!yourName` become true.

Comment: Ahh "!yourName" - so that's what they mean by "truthy" when evaluating : )

Comment: And ng-init replaces value="blabla" - Guess this angularBusiness changes a lot of things : )

Answer (score 0):

That's because by default `yourName` is `undefined`. Try like this.

```
<h1 ng-hide="yourName == '' || yourName == undefined ">Hello "{{yourName}}"</h1>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter your name">
        <hr>
        <h1 ng-show="yourName == ''">Who ARE you ?</h1>
        <h1 ng-hide="yourName == ''|| yourName == undefined ">Hello "{{yourName}}"</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry - 1 minute late, with the same answer (minus ng-init)